# Using TraceListener in another App Domain

Tags: c#, .net

Why TraceListener is derived from MarshalByRefObject. That heritance doesn't carry any benefits.

I can't use TraceListener after passing it through remoting in another domain, because TraceEventCache in method parameters doesn't have Serializable attribute.

So i can't call methods from TraceListener with such signature:

public override void TraceEvent(TraceEventCache eventCache, string source, TraceEventType eventType, int id, string message)